# How to unlist an executable location in the PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows-10

I'm just learning cmd and I listed brave browser's executable location in the path environment variable like this:

```
set brave="brave's executable location"
```

But I want to undo/delete this brave variable. How may I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to undo/delete this brave variable

`set brave=` will remove it:

> **Delete a variable**
>
> Type `SET` with just the variable name and an equals sign `=`

Exiting the `cmd` shell will also remove it:

> Changes made with `SET` will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Source:[Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

This is because `brave` is a local variable created in the environment space of the **current** cmd shell.

If you are working with a cmd batch file then consider using `setlocal` and `endlocal`

---

#### I listed brave browser's executable location in the path environment variable like this:

> ```
> set brave="brave's executable location"
> ```

You have not changed the `path` environment variable with the above command. You have created a new **local** variable called `brave` in the current cmd shell environment space. This variable is only valid for the duration of the cmd shell in which it has been set.

The `path` environment variable on the other hand is a **global** variable that belongs to the operating system. You can see its current value using the following command:

```
echo %path%
```

You can change the path variable by using:

```
set path=somevalue
```

Most users will not need to do this. **Warning - do not do this unless you completely understand the consequences of dong so.**

To see all the environment variables (both local and global) use:

```
set
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Windows Environment Variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)

Comment: Best answer by far! Cheers! I'm new to learning cmd, is there a book/resource you recommend to learn from scratch? I had never seen the command prompt until yesterday. I want to go from below zero to hero.

Comment: There are plenty of online resources if you search for "learn windows cmd". However, If you are starting from scratch I would recommend learning PowerShell instead. It's more powerful and in some ways easier to learn as it doesn't suffer from the idiosyncrasies of cmd.

Comment: So I reformulate my question. What books/resources do you recommend for learning powershell? Should I use books? Both? Thanks again!

Comment: We don't recommend learning resources on [su]. Again a Google search will provide plenty of links where you can start.

Answer (score 1):

You have not modified the PATH.

All you have done is create an environment variable named `brave` that
is local to the current CMD session.

Unless you explicitly use this variable's value (`%brave%`), the variable
has no influence on the execution of commands in the current CMD session.

If Brave executes afterward, it's because its folder is already in the PATH
environment variable, not because of your created variable.

Comment: "(Please study the subject before asking.)" that is on the edge of being rude.

Comment: And you haven't answered the question, which is how to delete the variable.

Comment: @DavidPostill: The poster seems to be under the misconception that this variable is added to the PATH. I'm trying to help : "How to unlist an executable location in the *PATH environment variable*?"